# Handling Exception and Testing it(JUnit5): SpringBoot RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Consider the below code, here I am writing a JUnit testcase in such a way that the rest call will throw a `CustomException` (status: `BAD_REQUEST`). I expect the error to get caught by the `HttpStatusCodeException`, but its getting caught by Exception and throws `InternalServerError`.

**Why is this happening, is my understanding wrong?**

When I try to execute the function normally as a `SpringBoot` app and making the other rest service throw a `Custom Exception`, everything works as Expected, but why its not working with the `JUnit` test case?

**Service**

```
public User getIt() {
    User user = null;
    try {
        ReqObject obj=new ReqObject();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("url", obj, Object.class);
        user = modelMapper.map(response.getBody(), User.class);

    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        throw new CustomException(ex.getStatusCode(), "Status Error", ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Unexpected Error", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return user;
}
```

**JUnit Testcase**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserApplicationTests {
    @InjectMocks
    MyService service;
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    void test(){
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(Object.class)))
                .thenThrow(new CustomException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "400", "Invalid"));

        HttpStatus status= Assertions.assertThrows(CustomException.class, ()->service.getIt()).getStatus();
        Assertions.assertTrue(status.is4xxClientError()); // throwing 500
    }
}
```

Comment: try `when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(User.class), eq(Object.class)))`

Comment: I made changes in the code and tried when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(ReqObject.class), eq(Object.class))), still throws 500 @Alex

Comment: Ok. I see. You should throw `HttpStatusCodeException` here `.thenThrow(new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))`